# Rewriting Django template {% for %} into a Model method

Tags: python, django, loops

I have existing code that works:

```
{% for author in seminar.authors.all %}
{{ author.first_name}} {{ author.last_name }}
{% if forloop.last %}{% else %},&nbsp;{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As you may have guessed, `seminar.authors` is a m2m field. Generic, nothing special.

I know how to write Model methods, but im not sure how to properly loop through each author item per seminar object and apply a comma if the current iteration is all but last.

Would it be alright to name this Model method `get_author_display`? Im not sure if this clashes with Django's built-in `get_*_display`.

furthermore, I'd love to support a few `forloop.last` conditions:

- 1 author name = no comma or "and"
- 2 author names = comma
- 3 or more author names = commas w/ "and" prepending the last author name.

but in an elegant manner. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your second extra requirement is correct? Surely with just two names you want "and" and no comma?

Anyway, there's nothing particularly difficult about this. The trick is to get the queryset's length first - note that it's actually more efficient to use `len` rather than `.count()` here, because `count()` on an unevaluated queryset does a separate call to the database.

```
def get_author_display(self):
    authors = self.authors.all()
    length = len(authors)
    output = []
    for i, author in enumerate(authors):
        val = "%s %s" % (author.first_name, author.last_name)
        if i == (length-1) and length > 2:
             val = "and " + val
        output.append(val)
    return ', '.join(output)
```

And no, there's nothing wrong with calling the method that: `authors` will never have `CHOICES` set, so won't get an automatic `get_foo_display` method.

Comment: Wow. That would have taken me a while to find myself. I think an adjustment needs to be made to the last line, as im getting output with ", and" e.g. "Katherine Fulton, Richard Rockefeller, and Larry Brilliant".